# How do I find the orthogonal projection of a point onto a plane

Tags: math, 3d

Lets say I have point (x,y,z) and plane with point (a,b,c) and normal (d,e,f).  I want to find the point that is the result of the orthogonal projection of the first point onto the plane.  I am using this in 3d graphics programming.  I want to achieve some sort of clipping onto the plane.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The projection of a point `q = (x, y, z)` onto a plane given by a point `p = (a, b, c)` and a normal `n = (d, e, f)` is

```
q_proj = q - dot(q - p, n) * n
```

This calculation assumes that `n` is a unit vector.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented this function in Qt using QVector3D:

```
QVector3D getPointProjectionInPlane(QVector3D point, QVector3D planePoint, QVector3D planeNormal)
{
    //q_proj = q - dot(q - p, n) * n
    QVector3D normalizedPlaneNormal = planeNormal.normalized();
    QVector3D pointProjection = point - QVector3D::dotProduct(point - planePoint, normalizedPlaneNormal) * normalizedPlaneNormal;
    return pointProjection;
}
```

Comment: This uses the same algorithm as the previous, accepted answer and uses a language not asked for. Just what does this answer add to the accepted answer?