# How to compute the inverse orthogonal projection of a point in the viewing plane onto a plane in the scene?

Tags: geometry, projection, quaternions, orthographic

Suppose I have a viewing plane `vn`, with an orientation `q1` and a plane in the scene `un` with an orientation `q2`.

`q1` and `q2` are quaternions.

How would I find the unknown point `ux, uy, uz` such that `proj_u_plane_vn` is equal to a known point `vx, vy, 0`?

Would the problem be simpler by finding the relative orientation `q2-q1`?

Right now I'm trying to do it with i, j and k values, but it seems like overkill and I'm not seeing the answer pop out without doing inverse trig, not that I would mind that, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Note: I think the correct answer would be `u = (q1 * q2^-1) * v` where ux,uy are the point in `un` and uz is the distance from vx, vy, 0 to ux, uy, 0.  I have yet to verify this, please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following values:

```
 vx, vy, vz; //These are the points in the viewing plane, which you know.
 q1, q2;     //The vectors describing the viewing and scene planes.
```

As you suspected, the trick to projection between planes is in using the relative orientations.

You should use your offsets (when you find the relative orientations) between planes to treat the scene plane as if it is offset from the front plane (the viewing plane).  This is not only easier to visualize, but it will also make the answers which you looked up more relevant.

Knowing this, you can use your relative orientation to define n in the following equation:

```
 q_proj = q - dot(q - p, n) * n
```

The projection of a point q = (x, y, z) onto a plane given by a point p = (a, b, c) and a normal n = (d, e, f).

Note that this answer was ripped from here: [How do I find the orthogonal projection of a point onto a plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942950/how-do-i-find-the-orthogonal-projection-of-a-point-onto-a-plane).

Comment: Yes, I had realized that after thinking about it for a bit. :D  My quaternion implementation provides a matrix representation which already contains the z-hat (`n`) after computing `q1 ( q2^-1) -> qt`, then I simply rotate `qt(p) -> p'`, solve `n.z * t - p'.z = 0`, then `q2( p' + (n)t ) -> p''` to get the spatial coordinate of that point in the plane in the scene.